# Twitter api version 2 throws Client Forbidden error

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

When I try to query recent search endpoint of twitter `/2/tweets/search/recent` it throws an exception

```
{
    "client_id": "xxxxx",
    "required_enrollment": "Standard Basic",
    "detail": "When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer app that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.",
    "registration_url": "https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/opt-in",
    "title": "Client Forbidden",
    "reason": "client-not-enrolled",
    "type": "https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/client-forbidden"
}
```

**Additional informations**

Authorization  `Oauth 1.0`

Signature Method `HMAC-SHA1`

Also provide consumer key,secret,access token,token secret

why this happen? i don't get any useful information when i search with this error `When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer app that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.` Please help..

Comment: In the developer portal, do you have a Project and an App set up? Or only Standalone Apps? This should show up on this page https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/projects-and-apps after you have use the portal opt-in URL from the error message.

Comment: I have a project and app already setup

Comment: @AndyPiper under the projects section I can see a project app where my app is listed

Comment: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/opt-in redirect me to the dashboard

Comment: How are you accessing the endpoint, is this from Postman, or from code? It sounds like you may be trying to use user authentication, have you tried using the Bearer Token for your app in your project?

Comment: Using postman,providing oauth authentication, I am not sure where can I get the bearer token

Comment: **Additional info**,when i try this end point https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=conversation_id:1346972806005858309 it returns Unauthorized if i search for https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=cristiano i got the above client-not-enrolled error

Comment: @soju Hi, have you solved it? I'm getting the same message ""reason": "client-not-enrolled""

Comment: @whitesiroi Hi,this is definetly twitter app related issue,my client gives me new app credentials and it works fine.sorry if that don't helps

Comment: @soju thank you for your reply, I found that I was able to apply for v2 labs here on the top of this page https://developer.twitter.com/en/account/labs & now it works. Good to hear that your stuff works too.

Answer (score 10):

Just create a project to the standalone app in the Twitter Developer Portal. And also ensure you have `v2 Access` tag under Projects and Apps => overview in front of your project name.

[image]

Comment: I'm getting same error, although my app is under project. My app is been for 4 years. I wanted to migrate to V2 endpoints. I was able to perform V2 GET requests with bearer token. As few V2 endpoints still use consumer keys and oauth tokens (oauth 1.0 a), they are getting failed.
URL: https://api.twitter.com/2/users/1391xxxxxxxxxxx30/following with 
post body as json {"target_user_id":"11348282"}

Please let me know solution

Comment: I was using a bearer token from standalone app hence the issue, Creating a new project and adding the standalone app in it fixed the issue. Also, ensure that under Project=>Overview your project has `v2 Access` tag

Comment: How do you apply for v2 if you don't have the access tag?

Comment: I deleted all the old apps, created a new project, and then created a new app within the project. I still do not see a v2 access tag in the application. Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 9):

### Twitter API v2 doesn't support search API on Free plan

Only APIs available with free plans are

Manage Tweets:

1. `POST /2/tweets`
2. `DELETE /2/tweets/:id`

User Lookups:

3. `GET /2/users/me`

---

[Check here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/products/free) for more details regarding pricing and features.

Comment: yes, twitter api v2 worked ok with the free plan untill a few months ago. I think they changed the policy

Answer (score 4):

Due to Twitter API changes, you can only post up to 1500 tweets with a free tier. To retrieve tweets you need to upgrade the package. [image]

Answer (score 2):

/2/tweets/search/recent is not available in the free plan.
See V2 endpoints available on the free plan here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/products/free
fk

Answer (score 0):

As some of the answers already made it clear that you need minimum basic plan to perform recent search, here is a simple python code to immediately check if you are getting tweets after upgrading to basic plan.

```
import requests
import os

# Replace with your Twitter Bearer Token
bearer_token = os.getenv("TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN")

# API endpoint URL
url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent"

# Parameters for the API request
params = {
    "query": "SEARCH_WORD",
    "max_results": 20  # 10-100 in basic plan
}

# Headers with Bearer Token
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {bearer_token}"
}

try:
    # Make the API request
    response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()  # Check for any request errors

    # Parse the JSON response
    data = response.json()

    # Check if the response contains tweets
    if "data" in data:
        # Print each tweet with tweet URL
        for tweet in data["data"]:
            tweet_id = tweet["id"]
            tweet_text = tweet["text"]
            tweet_url = f"https://twitter.com/user/status/{tweet_id}"
            print(f"Tweet ID: {tweet_id}\nTweet Text: {tweet_text}\nTweet URL: {tweet_url}\n")

    else:
        print("No tweets found in the response.")

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"Error making the API request: {e}")

except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
    print(f"Error parsing the JSON response: {e}")
```