# problem when authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2

Tags: twitter, tweepy, twitter-api-v2

i keep getting this error:
tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.
even tho i have access to API V2
I looked at this solution here:[Twitter api version 2 throws Client Forbidden error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65595139/twitter-api-version-2-throws-client-forbidden-error)
and i checked [it says it has v2 access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QVVk.png)

here is the code:

```
`client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token)

tweets=client.search_all_tweets(query=handle,start_time=start_time(7),max_results=100)`
```

NB:I already worked with API V2 and it was working just fine,i also regenerated bearer key